# Angular momentum decomposition in COM frame when COM rotating

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, collision

[image]
Here is the question. Now I want to understand the alternative method below to solve the angular momentum. Normally in a point we can decompose the angular momentum about the point into distance vector from the point to the center of mass cross product the momentum of the system, if it is a rigid body, plus the angular momentum as the object rotate about the center of mass. But we can do this is because the body rotate about the center of mass, is it right? Now in this problem the center of mass of the stick also rotate about the center of mass of stick-puck combination. Why does it can simply decompose the angular momentum of point C as the whole thing is rotating around the center of mass of the stick?

[image]